# How to find the smallest and the biggest number of items in array in Java?

Tags: java, arrays

I was wondering if there is any method to display the highest and the smallest number of items stored in array/linkedlist.

```
public Checkout()
{

   tillQueue = new LinkedList<String>(); 
   currentLen = 0;      
   lengthList = new ArrayList <Integer>();

   mean = 0; 
   r = new Random();
}


public void simulation()
{
    System.out.println("Time" + "\t" + "Rnd" + "\t" + "Queue Status");
    for (int t=2; t<10; t++) //number of time-steps in the simulation.
    {
        rndNumber = r.nextInt(6) +1; // generates random number between 1 and 6.          

        if (rndNumber==4 || rndNumber==2 || rndNumber==6) 
        {            
             // if rndNumber is 4, t is added to a queue.
                tillQueue.add(String.valueOf(t));
                currentLen++;

        }
        else if ((rndNumber==1 || rndNumber==3) && !tillQueue.isEmpty())
        {                              
            tillQueue.remove();
            currentLen--;
           //if rndNumber is either 1 or 3, person is removed from the queue
        }
```

and that's the outcome:

> Queue number 1
>
> Queue
>
> [2]
>
> [2, 3]
>
> [2, 3, 4]
>
> [3, 4]
>
> [3, 4]
>
> [4]
>
> Queue is empty
>
> Queue is empty
>
> Mean length of queue 1= 1.375
>
> Max length of queue 1= 0.0
>
> Min length of queue 1= 0.0

As you can see from the output the highest number of people is 3 (2,3,4) and lowest 0 (empty)
How can I calculate those values?

Comment: sort the list, then take the first and last values.

Comment: Make your own method will be O(n).. or build a collection with order (sorting it) then select the first and the last..

Answer (score 5):

You could use the Collections class.

```
Integer max_number = Collections.max(arrayList);
Integer min_number = Collections.min(arrayList);
```

See: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html

Comment: +1 for not reinventing the wheel :) A simple Java call is almost always better than implementing your own version.

Answer (score 0):

If your intent is to track the *length* of the list as it changes, you will need to calculate the number of members at each step. So, outside of the for loop, `int count = 0;` then, at the end of the loop add an conditional statement that updates if the current length is greater than the current max

```
public void simulation()
{
    System.out.println("Time" + "\t" + "Rnd" + "\t" + "Queue Status");
    int count = 0;
    for (int t=2; t<10; t++) //number of time-steps in the simulation.
    {
        //do all your stuff...

    if (count > tillQueue.size())
    {
        count = tillQueue.size();
    }
}
```

The same principle would apply to the least value, though I think in this case it is always 0?

Answer (score 0):

If you are intending to use lengthList,

Before the loop or business logic,

```
lengthList.add(tillQueue.size())
```

During the loop or any business logic, after any add or remove operations,

```
lengthList.add(tillQueue.size())
```

After your implementation is complete, as Sergio suggested,

```
Integer max_number = Collections.max(lengthList);
Integer min_number = Collections.min(lengthList);
```